# Не нажимаются кнопки в виджете PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qt-designer, qlistwidget

Начала недавно изучать *PyQt5*, да и *Python* в целом. Хочу сделать виджет, который должен открываться путем наведения курсора, но кнопки внутри виджета крайне странно жмутся.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы виджет открывался путем наведения не на невидимую кнопку, а путем наведения на сам виджет?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui  

class gg(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):                    # +++
        MainWindow.setObjectName('ОКОШЕЧКО')          # +++
        MainWindow.resize(850, 500)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)   # +++
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('')                 # +++
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget) # +++
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btn{\n"
"      background:none;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btn.setText('')                          # +++
        
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:grey;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btn.raise_()

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()     
        self.listWidget.addItems(["1", "2", "3", '4', '5'])
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.listWidget.itChecked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.widget)           # +++

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):                   # +++
        pass


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def itChecked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "Вы нажали: {}".format(item.text())
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gg):
    def __init__(self):                                    # +++
        super().__init__()                                 # +++
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.installEventFilter(self)     

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(50, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, checked, event):
        
        if self.btn is checked:                                
#            if event.type() == 2 and self.btn.isChecked():
            if event.type() == event.Enter:                                         # <----<
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
#            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btn.isChecked()):
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:                                       # <----<
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
             
        return super().eventFilter(checked, event)         # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или я чего-то не понимаю, но вам совсем не нужен виджет `QPushButton` - уберите его.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class gg(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.setObjectName('ОКОШЕЧКО')
        MainWindow.resize(850, 500)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccffbd;') 
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
        '''
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget) # +++
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btn{\n"
"      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 100);\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btn.setText('')                      
       self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        '''
# ?          ??????      
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background: white;")                      
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)                      
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 50, 500))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background: #7eca9c;")                   # grey
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
##        self.btn.raise_()

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()                                    
        self.listWidget.addItems(["   1 ", "   2 ", "   3    Hello World", '   4 ', '   5 '])
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.listWidget.item_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.widget)  

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):             
        pass


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):

    def item_clicked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "Вы нажали: {}".format(item.text())
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gg):
    def __init__(self):                 
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
##        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
##        self.btn.installEventFilter(self)

        self.frame2.installEventFilter(self)                                     # +++  frame2   

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(50, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
#        if self.btn is checked:  
        if self.frame2 is obj:                                                   # +++  frame2                            
            if event.type() == event.Enter:                                   
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:                                  
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
             
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]